# cannot view history for visual studiosafe

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I canno't view the history for a certain file in VSS. Erery time I click  on 'view history' or rollback or even the difference between two files, I get this error :

> SourceSafe was unable to finish writing a file. Check your available disk space, and ask the administrator to analyze your sourcesafe database.

I am trying to view the scripts that I added in the early morning, but I am not able to do that. I so in need them. what should I do ? is there a quick fix for it ?

I should mention that I am able to view the history of the new files that I added lately.

Comment: The error message tells you **exactly** what the problem is and what you need to do to fix it. I'm not sure what more you want us to say.

Comment: @KenWhite why I able to see the scripts that I added latetly ? and cleaning for the databse needs a day or two. Isn't there a quick way for that ?

Comment: Because it's a different area of the history? VSS is telling you it was unable to finish writing **a file**, which means that all other areas are fine. It's **a file** that has the problem. If the database requires analysis and repair, you have to do so; it's not optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSS uses a pair of files for each instance of a file in the database: one representing the latest version of the file, and one that represents the change history.  The error message is accurate.  Perform maintenance on the database.  In my experience do this monthly, along with frequent backups.  If you don't have a recent backup, it is likely that you have lost the history for the file, but may still have the latest version.